# getView() in CountDownTimer's onTick return sometimes null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I had recently a crash report where I could see that in the CountDownTimer's onTick method
the getView() call returns null.
I use the onTick method to display the remaining time in a textView. The textView is inside a Fragment.

Since the CountDownTimer runs in the UI thread I have no idea why this had happened.

What could be the cause for this and what is a possible workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code we're not very good at mind reading around here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Extended CountDownTimer in my own counter class with a TextView in it.

```
public class myCounter extends CountDownTimer
{
    TextView counter;

    public myCounter(final long millisInFuture, final long countDownInterval,
                    final TextView newCounter)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        counter = newCounter;
        counter.setText("Left: " + millisInFuture);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        counter.setText("GO!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        counter.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}
```

Then in my Activity:

```
public class CountdownViewActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.countdownview);

            final Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

            //Send total time in milliseconds, the interval to display at, and the TextView from your xml it should display in
            final myCounter countdown = new myCounter(timeInSeconds * 1000, 1000, (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4));
            startBtn.setOnClickListener(startClick(countdown));
//MoreStuff
    }

    private OnClickListener startClick(final myCounter countdown)
    {
        return new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                countdown.start();
            }
        };
    }
}
```